# Importance of __getitem___ : HTML Parsing using Python

Tags: python, parsing, magic-methods

```
class mainprogram():
 def getData(self, file, begin, end):
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    f = open(file);
    rawcontent = f.read()

    #Get main content
    content = rawcontent.split('<div id="header"')[1];
    content = content.split('</html>')[0];

    del parsed_data[:]
    html = content.split(begin)[1];
    html = html.split(end)[0];
    parser.feed(html);
    result = list(parsed_data);
    return result;
```

---

I'm in the stage of practising Python and while I was doing an assignment related to Python I was stuck. The above code Snippet uses htmlparser for parsing .msg file to convert into csv format.
Could any one explain me the what does [1] [0] signify in these below lines

```
content = rawcontent.split('<div id="header"')[1];
content = content.split('</html>')[0];
```

Presently I'm using Python community version for development, when I highlight that particular [1] or [0] its showing up as

```
class list

def __getitem__(self, y)
```

Comment: `list[index]` retrieves the item at position `index` from `list`. This functionality is implemented as a `__getitem__(self, index)` function. Basically, `rawcontent.split('')[0]` splits `rawcontent` into a list of strings, and then retrieves the first value (`[0]`). Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

As described in [special method names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__), the method name `__getitem__()` allows a class to override the `foo[bar]` syntax.  Lists do this to provide both subscripting (e.g. `foo[5]`) and slicing (`foo[1:5]`).  Dictionaries do this to provide key lookup.